# how to detect parameter is not empty on laravel?

Tags: laravel, parameters, isnullorempty

how to detect parameter is not empty on laravel?

example i have params body like below :

```
{
  email : "haha@example.com"
}
```

when params email is exist's i want echo some string, example : "parameter email is exist's"

if params email not exits just echo "parameter is not exist's"

```
if(params['email'] != null) {
  print params email is exists's
}else{
  print params email doesn't exists's
}
```

how do that, i'm new on php / laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code

```
if( isset(params['email']) && !empty(params['email']) ) {
  echo " params email exists"
}else{
  echo  "params email doesn't exist"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Object oriented Laravel way is:

```
if($email = array_get($params, 'email')){
   echo " params email exists";
}else{
   echo  "params email doesn't exist";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use php build in [empty()](http://php.net/empty) function which checks if array key exists, is not null and is not empty according to data type.

```
if (!empty($params['email']) {
  // not empty
}
```

**From manual:**

Returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value. Otherwise returns TRUE.

The following things are considered to be empty:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if the array key exists use

```
if(array_key_exists('email',$params)){
//true
}
```

to check if the key exists and its not empty use

```
   if(array_key_exists('email',$params)&&!empty($params['email']){
    //true
    }
```

see Robert's answer for what is seen as empty by the empty function.